# Woocommerce core script overwrites custom CSS styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am writing full custom CSS for a Woocommerce shop. Most of the styling is relatively straightforward; I just don't seem to be able to style the select dropdowns:

Once the page is loaded JavaScript overwrites the custom styling on the select and applies core styles from `/assets/css/chosen.css`. Specifically it sets `width: 100% !important`.

Is there a way to stop this behaviour (stop or overwrite the script) without having to edit the core files?

Has anyone dealt with this previously?

**EDIT**

Actually it does not apply to all select dropdowns. It looks like it only applies to the `div` with class `chosen-container` that replaces the `select`. [Here](http://snag.gy/3va22.jpg)'s a screenshot.

Comment: Is this applying to all select dropdowns? Do you have an example?

Comment: It doesn't, actually. I've just edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally find it easiest to unset all styles, copy the styles from woocommerce.css to my own stylesheet and edit them from there.

Unset all default styles

```
// Don't load woocommerce style sheets
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' );
```

Enqueue your own stylesheet

```
function wp_enqueue_woocommerce_style(){
    wp_register_style( 'woocommerce', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/woocommerce.css' );
    if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'woocommerce' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_woocommerce_style' );
```

Copy all woocommerce styles into your own stylesheet and freely edit them from there. Or you up the priority of you current custom stylesheet so it loads before woocommerce.css. Something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_woocommerce_style', 15 );
```

Comment: Even if I don’t load the woocommerce style sheets with this code _and_ disable any other CSS on the site, I still get this element styled and with 100% width! [Here](http://snag.gy/ZPc1I.jpg)’s a screenshot. I’m sure at this point that the element is styled by a core script, which loads a core stylesheet. What would be the most clinical way of messing with the core files?

Comment: I see, are you building your own theme or did you buy one? I want to inspect the code. I suggest you systematically disable JS files until you find the function that is adding it.

Comment: Good idea, that's working for me! I disabled the Chosen script and style like [this](http://gregrickaby.com/remove-woocommerce-styles-and-scripts/).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to remove !important from the CSS attribute in the corresponding Javascript file. In general, !important as CSS attribute should be avoided. When the !important attribute is removed from the Javascript, you should be able to overwrite the specific CSS attribute with your own CSS.